# Writing new Excel(xlsx) file using Apache poi produces file with more memory

Tags: java, apache-poi

Below java code creates an xlsx file but the memory used by the generated file is 1 X 4 Eg: if a xlsx file is 1Mb then generated file from POI will be 4Mb, this some times throws Memory exception error.

there are Two Array-list of Array-lists one containing header and the other containing data, ordersFields contains header and materialData contains Actual data.

```java
Row newRow = null;
Workbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
String data = "";

// Print Column Headers
newRow = sheet.createRow(0);
for(int i = 0; i < orderedFields.size(); i++) {
    newRow.createCell(i).setCellValue(orderedFields.get(i));
}
// Print Data
for (int i = 0; i < materialData.size(); i++) {
    newRow = sheet.createRow(i+1);
    for (int j = 1; j < materialData.get(i).size(); j++) {
        newRow.createCell(j-1).setCellValue(materialData.get(i).get(j));
    }
}

ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
workbook.write(outByteStream);
workbook = null;
byte [] outArray = outByteStream.toByteArray();
response.setContentType("application/ms-excel");
response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
response.setHeader("Expires:", "0"); // eliminates browser caching
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write(outArray);
outStream.flush();
outArray = null;
outByteStream.reset();
```

The exported file produces 1X4 memory used xlsx file. please help me to get exported file to be utilised the exact memory.

Comment: Why do you think that the in-memory read/write format would be exactly the same size as the on-disk format? (Hint - it won't!)

Comment: @Gagravarr The xlsx file which i edited and saved in my local machine ( Excel Application processed to compress the file memory) cannot be implemented programatically?

Comment: Apache POI can happily let you edit and save your file, but it isn't excel! It needs to transform the data as it loads it into something it can work with, and that takes more memory than the native excel disk format

Comment: @Gagravarr is there any possibility where i get the length of the string and set the cell memory which can reduce the excel file. the problem is i have huge data to export like 10,000 with 50 columns so the export time takes more than 50 seconds with appropriately 100Mb of file size, which is inappropriate i think to give to users.. is there any solution to shrink the file size ?. please let me know.